# Spring integration - multi inbound adapters not working

Tags: spring, adapter, spring-integration, inbound

In my project I use 9 (nine) int-ip:udp-inbound-channel-adapter's and one jms:inbound-channel-adapter. Jms adapters receives messages from server. Everything worked fine, but when i added another (10th) int-ip:udp-inbound-channel-adapter jms stopped received any messages. When i removed randomly one of udp-adapters jms arrived. I use openMq. There is no errors or exceptions. Whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The default taskScheduler bean has a pool of 10 threads. Each UDP adapter uses one of these threads to receive packets.

Simply define an explicit scheduler with that name with a larger pool size

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="20"/>
```

Comment: I have opened a JIRA issue to fix this. https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-2648